# String comparision in php doesn't work if I use an object

Tags: php, string, string-comparison

I'm comparing two strings in php.
When I compare them like this it works:

```
if ("Original Mix" == "Original Mix")
    echo "ok";
else
    echo "not ok";
```

But when I compare it with my object, it doesn't.
I tried to echo my object and the result is: Original Mix

```
if ($traccia->remix == "Original Mix")
    echo "ok";
else
    echo "not ok";
```

what's wrong with php?

Comment: Can you `var_dump` on `$traccia->remix`?

Comment: I dont think anything is wrong with PHP :) You might want to verify the contents of `$traccia->remix`

Comment: be sure there are not any **invisible** chars at the 2 ends such as spaces, tabs...

Comment: Try: `if(trim((string)$traccia->remix) == 'Original Mix")`

Comment: @DaveChen var_dump blocks my computer so I think there's a bigger problem than just the comparison one. Any suggestion?

Comment: By *blocks*, do you mean, (1) it returns a white screen, or (2) freezes your computer? I'm thinking that it will return something like, `string(13) "Original Mix "`, or `NULL`. Either case, you'll need to find where `$traccia->remix` is being set and find where the data inconsistency exists.

Comment: I have already tried to trim, cast, ecc..
I also tried to "normalize" the two strings from Original Mix to ORIGINALMIX but it doesn't work

Comment: Can you show the class declaration for `$traccia`? [It works fine for me](https://eval.in/private/5d607b14c88fb4).

Comment: @DaveChen it freezes my computer.
the variable is set in a previous function that returns $traccia:
    $traccia = AnalizzaPagina_Traccia($link);        
    $risultati = RicercaTraccia($traccia);

RicercaTraccia does the comparison

Comment: Okay. You'll need to provide the code for `AnalizzaPagina_Traccia`, what `$link` is. Instead of `var_dump`, does `print_r` work? Also try `view-source` when you echo.

Comment: I solved the problem, I looked at the assignment of the variable and there wasn't a string.
thank you very much!